# JDBC MySQL connection - error reading communication package

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

Since I've been moved from Windows to Ubuntu I cannot start my Java Spring MVC application anymore. It is not possible to establish the MySQL database connection. Before moving to Ubuntu I did not have any problems with the DB connection (and I did not change the code).

**What I do:**

My Spring app uses the following connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?user=mydbuser&password=mypassword
```

**What the error is:**

Spring only tells me that there is no database connection. But when I look into the DB logs, I can see the following error:

```
Aborted connection 6 to db: 'mydatabase' user: 'mydbuser' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

**What I already have tried:**

I am able to login via the MySQL console with `mydbuser`. The database is existing and my user has all rights. The connection problem only exists from the Spring application.

I followed many advises from stackoverflow, like setting the following variables:

```
SET @@global.log_error_verbosity = 2;
SET @@global.max_connections = 400;
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
```

Do you have any ideas what I can try or what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have this line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

If not add it, or change your connection string to:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase?user=mydbuser&password=mypassword
```